# Можно ли дать пользователям доступ к созданию страниц в конструкторе Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, gutenberg

Хочу добавить на свой сайт возможность создавать личный блог с функционалом конструктора (tilda, wix и т. д.). Могу ли я дать доступ всем пользователям к созданию страниц в конструкторе Gutenberg. Во всех материалах, которые мне удалось найти страницы редактировались только из админки.

Comment: Хочу добавить на свой сайт (написанный не на WordPress) => в конструкторе Gutenberg -- какая здесь связь?

Comment: Убрал эту пометку.

Comment: [How to Enable Frontend Editing with Gutenberg Blocks (Part 1)](https://webdevstudios.com/2020/08/04/frontend-editing-gutenberg-blocks-1/) и [How to Enable Frontend Editing with Gutenberg Blocks (Part 2)](https://webdevstudios.com/2020/08/11/frontend-editing-gutenberg-blocks-2/)